# Como fazer a função fread() buscar dados a cada 30 segundos sem atualizar a página

Tags: php, html, file-get-contents

Estou querendo que a função `fread()` ou `file_get_contents()` busque dados no arquivo a cada 30s, mas sem atualizar a página, tentei e  não conseguir como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: Por favor alguém pode me ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize ajax, para saber mais leia esse [documento](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) da Mozilla em Português

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Mude o valor da variavel url.
var url = "https://api.github.com/users?";

function get(url) {
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          var dadosRecebidos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          var out = "";
          out += '<a href="' + dadosRecebidos[0].url + '">' + dadosRecebidos[0].login + '</a><br>';
          document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = out;
      }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  // 30000 milisegundos = 30 segundos
  setTimeout(function(){
    get(url);
  }, 30000);
}
get(url);
```

```html
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: Não está funcionando não

Comment: Tentei, mas não funcionou

Comment: Edita sua pergunta e coloca seu código html e php.